# Approximating a Fortran_COMPILER_ID CMake generator expression

Tags: cmake, fortran

I am (attempting to) leverage CMake's generator expressions to support ***generation-time*** compiler flag configuration based on the compiler vendor for a Fortran project.

Unfortunately, while the relevant [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) describes how maybe accomplished in C and C++ projects (see the `C_COMPILER_ID` and `CXX_COMPILER_ID` logical expressions, respectively), there is no mention of a Fortran analogue.

I have confirmed there is no `Fortran_COMPILER_ID` generator expression, which emits the following error when used:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:<line number> (target_compile_options):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<Fortran_COMPILER_ID:GNU>

  Expression did not evaluate to a known generator expression
```

Is it possible to approximate this behavior for a Fortran project?

Edit:

minimum example of desired behavior

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.2 ) 

project( myProject LANGUAGES Fortran )

set( fortran_module_directory "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/modules" CACHE PATH "directory for fortran modules" )
file( MAKE_DIRECTORY ${fortran_module_directory} ) 
set( CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${fortran_module_directory} )

set( myProject_GNU_DEBUG_flags "flag1" "flag2" )
set( myProject_GNU_RELEASE_flags "flag3" "flag4" )
set( myProject_Intel_DEBUG_flags "flag5" "flag6")
set( myProject_Intel_RELEASE_flags "flag7" "flag8" )
# other compilers    

add_library( myProject STATIC 
             ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mySource.f90
             ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/myOtherSource.f90 )

target_include_directories( myProject PUBLIC ${fortran_module_directory} )

target_compile_options( njoy PRIVATE 
$<$<Fortran_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${myProject_GNU_DEBUG_flags}>>
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${myProject_GNU_RELEASE_flags}>>>
$<$<Fortran_COMPILER_ID:Intel>:
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${myProject_Intel_DEBUG_flags}>>
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${myProject_Intel_RELEASE_flags}>>>
# other compilers
)
```

Comment: Can you show a minimum working example? Also, did you enable Fortran for the cmake project? I compare the variable CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID to set flags.

Comment: I was under the impression the `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID` variable was specified at configuration time and remained invariant if a multi-configuration generator (e.g. Xcode or Visual Studios) switched its compiler. Is that not the case?

Comment: Ok, I mixed the definitions. I must admit that I use command-line cmake and configure for a single compiler at a time. There is no trace of Fortran_COMPILER_ID in the source of cmake, as seen here: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/325c6153088c673569971958f107f6cb97b67c50/Source/cmGeneratorExpressionNode.cxx or in the docs or in the mailing list. If you really want this you'll have to ask the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in a HDF5 [CMakeLists.txt](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/fortran/src/CMakeLists.txt) inspiration for a way that might work.
For example:

```
set (Fortran_COMPILER_ID CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID)

target_link_libraries(target PUBLIC
  $<$<STREQUAL:"${Fortran_COMPILER_ID}","GNU">:"-lgfortran">
  $<$<STREQUAL:"${Fortran_COMPILER_ID}","Intel">:"-lifcore">
  )
```

Comment: Ultimately, this is what I ended up inventing as well. Thus far, it hasn't bitten me, but it's too bad we don't have the same degree of support in CMake for Fortran as for C and C++